# brew link php55 does not work

Tags: macos, homebrew

I tried to install php55 which works fine itself, but the linking does not work. Which means I cannot install any modules via brew.

```
$ brew link php55
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.17... Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.16/include/php
```

Brew tries to link 5.5.16 but it should use 5.5.17. I already reinstall php55 again a few times and used "brew cleanup" in between.

How can I link it correctly?

Answer (score -1):

Remove it with "brew remove php55". It will automatically look at the other version afterwards. Don't forget to relink it with "brew unlink php55 && brew link php55".